# What does it mean to be an 'unrepentant realist'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the context of personality and personal characteristics.
The person is described as being an 'unrepentant realist'.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking for here. Do you need to know the meaning of the word "unrepentant"? Or the word "realist"? Or is it a contextual thing where you don't know why the two words are associated, or how they describe a person's personality? If it's the latter I think you need to give more context because "realist" could mean many things.

Comment: I would expect someone self describing as an "unrepentant realist" to quite likely be either an atheist or to have ideas about god that were far from the mystical...to the extent that can be.  I would expect them to bristle at sayings like "Everything happens for a reason." or "It just wasn't meant to be." when things in life go wrong etc..  I'm not placing this as an answer because, without knowing context this could be a wrong interpretation ...

Answer (score 0):

Unrepentant means :

> showing no regret for one's wrongdoings

[(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unrepentant)

A realist is:

> A person who accepts a situation as it is and is prepared to deal with
>   it accordingly

[(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/optimist)

Compare realist, with optimist:

> A person who tends to be hopeful and confident about the future or the
>   success of something

[(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/realist)

A realist takes matters as they are, and is sometimes *accused* of being miserly (bordering on pessimistic) in their world view.

It is this sense of the word realist that is being employed here. The phrase is acknowledging the fact that those with a more optimistic outlook on life might chide a realist for their lack of imagination when it comes to imagining a better future or outcome.

Obstinately however the speaker is embracing their realistic viewpoint in spite of this. Unrepentantly in spite of any accusation that they should be more optimistic.